# Pandas melt not giving the wanted output (ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '198|260|157|136|136')

Tags: python, pandas, recommendation-engine

I'm implementing a recommendation system example I've found at Medium.

In data preparation, it has this 'transaction' structure with the csv read by pandas:

```
print(transactions.shape)
transactions.head()
```

The output is something like this:

```
(62483, 2)
customerId  products
0   0   20
1   1   2|2|23|68|68|111|29|86|107|152
2   2   111|107|29|11|11|11|33|23
3   3   164|227
4   5   2|2
```

Need to split it into a 'data' structure, which might look like this:

[image: Example]

The code in the post to do that is:

```
data = pd.melt(transactions.set_index('customerId')['products'].apply(pd.Series).reset_index(), 
             id_vars=['customerId'],
             value_name='products') \
    .dropna().drop(['variable'], axis=1) \
    .groupby(['customerId', 'products']) \
    .agg({'products': 'count'}) \
    .rename(columns={'products': 'purchase_count'}) \
    .reset_index() \
    .rename(columns={'products': 'productId'})
data['productId'] = data['productId'].astype(np.int64)
```

However, when I run it, the output gives me this error "ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '198|260|157|136|136'", because it's not splitting the values in 'productId' column.

I'm getting something like this:

```
(61282, 3)
customerId  productId   purchase_count
0   0   198|260|157|136|136 1
1   0   19|19|19    1
2   0   1|1|31|31   1
3   0   20  1
4   0   216|52|260|93|93|93 1
```

Any ideas?

Comment: `"because it's not splitting the values in 'productId' column"` where are you asking it to do that?

Comment: I'm just following the tutorial. After the execution of the cell with the given code, according to the post, I should get something like the posted image... I'm not familiar with pandas. Don't really know why I'm getting something different from the post...

Answer (score 0):

For those facing the same issue, it was solved with this code before the use o melt function:

```
transactions['products'] = transactions['products'].apply(lambda x: [int(i) for i in x.split('|')])
```